# passing id to SharePoint modal

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm using REST API to bring items back from my SharePoint list and then building a table with that link as I loop though each item.  In the last column of the table, the item is a link that is supposed to pop open a modal window when clicked.  The problem that I am having is passing the ID to the modal.  Any ideas how to accomplish this?  What I have does not even bring up the modal.

```
function getProjectContracts() {
   //Using REST to retrieve data    
}

getProjectContracts();

function contractComplete(data) {
    var contractHtml="";
    var typeArray = [];
    var headingName = "";
    for(var i =0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) 
    {              
        headingName = data.d.results[i].ContractType;

        if (typeArray.indexOf(headingName) === -1){
            typeArray.push(headingName);

            contractHeadHtml = "<tr><td colspan='14' id='" + headingName + "' style='background-color:#eeeeee'><b>" + headingName + "</b></td></tr>";
            console.dir(contractHeadHtml);
            $("#tblContract").append(contractHeadHtml);
        }
            contractHtml = "<tr>"+
            "<td style='text-align:center'><a href="+_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/Lists/Project%20Contracts/Item/displayifs.aspx?List=a20a6951%2Dced3%2D4faf%2Db920%2D3702c532a2af&ID="+data.d.results[i].ID+"&Source=../SitePages/ProjectSummary.aspx?id="+getUrlVars()["id"]+"&ContentTypeId=0x01006633A0266D59004FB176A06FF9491281><img src='../images1/edit-notessp.png'></a></td>"+
            "<td>"+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].ContractNumber)+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].SolicitationRestriction)+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].SolicitationType)+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].ActualAwardValue)+"</td>"+                                                                      
            "<td>"+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].FirmAwarded)+"</td>"+                                                                                
            "<td>"+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].CategorizationOfFirm)+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].PONumber)+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+data.d.results[i].Design_x002d_Build+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+checkForNull(moment(data.d.results[i].ActualContractPackageComplete).format("L"))+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].ActualPackageAcceptedByContracti)+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].ActualObligation)+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].ActualBidOpeningNegotiation)+"</td>"+
            "<td><a href=../SitePages/contractMod.aspx?id="+checkForNull(data.d.results[i].ContractNumber)+"  id=editMod>"+anyLetter(data.d.results[i].ContractNumber)+"</a></td>"+       
            console.log("page context::::: "+_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);                                                                               "</tr>";                                

            $("#tblContract").append(contractHtml);
    }                                                                                                                                              
}

var modLink = document.getElementById("editMod");

modLink.addEventListener("click", openInDialog)  //<-- not sure how to pass "data.d.results[i].ContractNumber"

function openInDialog()
{
    var urlValue =getUrlVars()["id"];
    AddListItem(urlValue);
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("wait for a few seconds"); }, 50000);
    var pageUrl = pageUrl=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/SitePages/departmentalGSF.aspx?id="+urlValue;
    var dlgWidth = 800;
    var dlgHeight = 600;
    var dlgAllowMaximize = true;
    var dlgShowClose = true;
    var needCallBackFunction = false;
    var options = {
        url: pageUrl,
        width: dlgWidth,
        height: dlgHeight,
        allowMaximize: dlgAllowMaximize,
        showClose: dlgShowClose,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: CloseDialogCallback

   };

    if(needCallBackFunction)
    {
        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseDialogCallback);
    }
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}

function anyLetter(cNumber) {
//alert(cNumber);
    if (cNumber.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
    //alert("match");
                    return "View/Edit";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When your function is called from the eventListener, you should have `this` already bound to it. You can find more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024483/how-to-pass-parameter-to-function-using-in-addeventlistener). Pass over whichever function from the web side (code not given above for the link coming in) and access it with `this.(your variable/parameter here)`. Once you have that value, pass it to your modal function as a parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work.  Here's a mock-up of what I'm trying to do.  Click the 'Edit' link.   http://jsfiddle.net/isogunro/516t2966/3/

Comment: You have a link that has both an href and an onclick, which is triggering two actions (navigate and function), which aren't going to work together. A button may be more appropriate for what you're doing. Also, you're building HTML code in javascript. You should probably consider moving to a solution like Angular for handling that more easily.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply pass the id to the function

```
<a href='...' onclick='javascript:openInDialog(id); return false'>Add/Edit</a>
```

Comment: I can't get it to work.  Here's a jsfiddle mock-up    http://jsfiddle.net/isogunro/516t2966/3/

Comment: In JSFiddle, you'd need to set the load type to body for the functions to register. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/516t2966/12/

Comment: What exactly did you change besides adding "return false;"?

Comment: JavaScript settings on JSFiddle (click on the settings gear icon) - changed load type.

Answer (score 2):

You already pass the `id` into the URL of your modal:
`var pageUrl = pageUrl=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/SitePages/departmentalGSF.aspx?id="+urlValue;`

So you can get it from the URL...

If your `departmentalGSF.aspx` loads the regular Sharepoint libraries, then you can call `GetUrlKeyValue('id')` into the `departmentalGSF.aspx` page. Otherwise you have to parse your URL.

**Attention**: I've noticed that Sharepoint returns an error when we try to call a page with a parameter `ID`. So I usually use another name, like `?ref=1` (instead of `?ID=1`), and then I use `GetUrlKeyValue('ref')` to get my ID.